# htaccess regex to grab additional field

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have the following regex although it only picks one variable and puts that in user like user contains user/url, how would I modify this to grab the url variable seperately in $2.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/?[^/]*)$ http://example.com/index.php?sub=%1&url=$1 [P,NC,QSA,L]
```

I need this to translate

```
http://sub.example.com/user/url
```

to

```
http://example.com/index.php?sub=%1&user=$1&url=$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex to capture 2 values from `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` doesn't seem correct.

You may use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?/?$  http://example.com/index.php?sub=%1&user=$1&url=$2 [P,NC,QSA,L]
```

I assume you have `mod_proxy` setup since you're using `P` flag.

Comment: Thanks I needed the parameters to be optional so I updated it to     RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]+)/?$ http://example.com/index.php?sub=%1&url=$1 [P,NC,QSA,L]